# Elements are not floating after a page break in print preview or print in Firefox(latest version)

Tags: html, css, firefox, printing

I am trying to print multiple document formats, but for some reason in Firefox the format is messed up beyond the first page. I have floating elements and they align correctly in the first page but break on the second page in print preview. I posted the code in jsfiddle and underneath. If you copy the code to your local machine, you can try it and see what I mean. It works fine on Chrome, IE 10, 9 and safari. Unfortunately not Firefox. I was wondering is this a Firefox bug, is there a turn around? I can use a table and it fix the problem but I prefer not to. Help is really appreciated.

http://jsfiddle.net/2xpDP/1/

```
     .hide { display: none; }
     .left { float: left; }
     .right { float: right; }
     .text-center { text-align: center; }
     .text-left { text-align: left; }
     .text-right { text-align: right; }

     .clearfix:before, .clearfix:after { content: ""; display: table; }
     .clearfix:after { clear: both; }
     .clearfix { *zoom: 1; }
     .clear { clear: both; }
     .align-top { vertical-align: top; }

     div.page { margin: 0 auto; width: 720px; font-family: Helvetica; font-size: 12px;}
     .invoice h2 { color: #ccc; }
     .invoice-header-top { border-bottom: 2px solid #ccc; padding-bottom: 10px; }
     .invoice-header-top img { width: 300px; height: 125px; }
     .invoice-header-top .formatType { width: 239px; margin-left: 40px; text-align: left; }

     @media print {
        div.page {page-break-after: always;}
     }

    <div class="page clear clearfix">
        <div class="invoice clear clearfix">
            <div class="invoice-header-top clear clearfix">
                <div class="left">
                    <img src=" http://placehold.it/350x150"></div>
                <div class="left formatType">
                    <h2>INVOICE
                    </h2>
                </div>
                <div class="right text-left">
                    <b>Test Data</b>
                    <br>
                    Test Data<br>
                    Test Data<br>
                    Test Data<br>
                    Test Data</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="page clearfix clear">
        <div class="invoice clearfix clear">
            <div class="invoice-header-top clear clearfix">
                <div class="left">
                    <img src=" http://placehold.it/350x150"></div>
                <div class="left formatType">
                    <h2>INVOICE
                    </h2>
                </div>
                <div class="right text-left company-info">
                <b>Test Data</b><br>
                    Test Data<br>
                    Test Data<br>
                    Test Data<br>
                    Test Data</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because the content property of your pseudo elements is empty. Add anything in those quotation marks (besides a hit on the space bar) and you'll see that your divs do align properly in FF (print view).

IE<8 doesn't support :before and :after so if you want to make this print identically in all the browsers out there I'd get rid of em.. Good luck!

Comment: Adding anything in the quotation will show that value. This will not fix the problem cause now you have unneeded content showing.

Comment: I'm not saying it doesn't mess up your design, but it IS the reason why your divs do not align properly in FF print view.. And it seems like you're working on something that needs to perform identical over multiple browsers, so get rid of the pseudo elements in your css and style it differently!